# How to use opencv for poster detection

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

[image]

Is it possible to use opencv for **better** detection of posters (see example image)? I have tried following approach:

1. create mask of higher intensity pixels (higher v value)
2. apply erosion and dilation to remove noise and make smooth.
3. findContours and draw bounding boxes.

Result of this approach is only good if there are lights behind the posters(poster glowing). However, for my goal is to detect posters even when its not in the highest intensities. Please anyone guide me about it.

Comment: Poster detection in this image only? Or in *any* image that includes posters?

Comment: in any image this one is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

First thought was neural nets...  and openCV has an implementation:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/neural_networks.html

They call them 'Multi Layer Perceptrons'

Other machine learning examples in openCV here:

http://bytefish.de/blog/machine_learning_opencv/

Answer (score 0):

If you know how the posters, you want to detect, look like, you could search for keypoints and match them by their descriptors.
See the example [Features2D + Homography to find a known object](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html) in the documentation for code.